# Will the resistor fail in this small circuit?

Tags: resistors, raspberry-pi

- I was looking at [this project](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/balloon-pi-tay-popper/worksheet/) to make a balloon popper with a Raspberry Pi and very few components
- The "essence" of this project is a 12 ohm resistor connected to the positive and negative terminals of a 9V battery
- Won't the average resistor (say 0.5W) fail in this scenario?

  - My (potentially flawed) reasoning:

    - ((9V * 9V) / 15Ω) = 5.4W
    - 5.4W > 0.5W

Comment: Your reasoning is fine. However the balloon would normally fail first. At which point it's natural to release the button... Then there's a race between the resistor and the battery as to which fails first. That depends how fresh the battery is; it won't supply 5W for very long!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the balloon succumbs in about 5-10 seconds, but will reusing the resistor over and over for such an interval cause it to eventually fail?

Comment: This seems a bit over-engineered to me. What's wrong with a pin?

Comment: This project seems to rely on putting more power into the resistor than its power rating so that it gets hot enough to pop the balloon. If you used a 5W resistor it probably wouldn't get hot enough to pop the balloon.

Comment: Yes but my money's on the battery to fail first. And resistors are cheaper than batteries, so who cares?

Comment: @SteveG Ahh, OK. Wasn't sure if a resistor with a higher power rating would still get hot or not. Thanks.

Comment: _Will it eventually fail?_ When using any electronic part outside of its specification there are no guarantees what will happen. But with a 9V battery, and if you limit the time that its on to 10 seconds it should last a long time. What's the worst that can happen if it fails? You're not using a balloon popper in a life critical application are you?

Comment: @IanBland For a pin-based approach, I could only think of a push-pull solenoid with a pin attached, which would be difficult to adequately attach to a balloon, not to mention the increase in cost and weight. I'd be happy to hear a better solution for using a Raspberry Pi to pop a balloon. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It's the difference between expecting regular failure and having ample replacements on hand or not. Pretty important.

Comment: @SteveG Remotely popping confetti-filled balloons at the climax of an event, so no, not life critical, but I would like it to work. :) Thanks again for your insights.

Comment: @dminuoso I may be old fashioned, but using a computer to pop a balloon at all seems like overengineering to me, likewise a solenoid. I think I would just hold a pin in my hand and make a short stabbing motion at the balloon, kind of thing.

Comment: I would use a small piece of heating resistance wire instead of a resistor, e.g. Kanthal. It has a lower mass and smaller surface area, so it is quicker to heat up. Kanthal is designed to be used at temperatures up to 1400°C, much higher than any normal resistor. By choosing the wire gauge, the length of wire, and the power source, you can get a pretty flexible solution. For instance, you could use a short and thin wire to pop a single balloon using very little power, or you could use one long (and thicker) wire and more power to pop multiple balloons.

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely possible that the resistor will fail when driven at 10 times its rated power. If it does, it will almost certainly do so by getting hot enough to pop the balloon. (This is called Letting The Magic Smoke Out. Did you know that every bit of electronics gear runs on magic? It's true. Each part contains a bit of Magic Smoke which makes it work. If you abuse the part it will go pop! and let the magic smoke out. Then the part doesn't work any more. Try it, you'll see. Logic is wonderful.)

In fact, I'd be tempted to use a 1/4 watt resistor instead of a 1/2 watt resistor because it will get hot faster and fail more quickly. Either way the balloon will pop more quickly.

In general, higher wattage resistors work on one of two principles, either they are physically bigger or they use a more robust material. If bigger, for the same power they spread it out over a larger volume and transfer it to the environment through a larger surface. From the same product line, a 1/4 watt and a 1/2 watt resistor will reach the same temperature at rated maximum.

Higher-wattage specialty resistors are typically a very high-temperature ceramic body with a resistive material which can handle higher temperatures without failing. I once had an array of 25-watt resistors which I was using as a dummy load in a test set, and forgot to turn on the cooling fan. The test auto-terminated when the solder connecting the wires to the resistors melted and the wire fell away and opened the circuit. Resoldering the wire and remembering to turn on the fan let me continue in very short order - the resistors were fine.